# How do I kill an unattended scheduled task?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a runaway windows task, if I were running it as a logged in user I would use Process Explorer (procexpe.exe) and look for the related cmd.exe and kill it there, but this one is running with a user who is not logged in.

I can't figure out how to kill it.

Comment: It still shows up in process explorer -- though you might be forced to launch it with admin privies.

Comment: Any particular version of Windows?

Comment: `but this one is running with a user who is not logged in` What? How? If the user logs out, their processes should end. If it is still running, then it must be a hung process that cannot be killed, so a reboot would have been required.

Comment: Did you try task manager/process explorer with admin privileges?

Comment: @Synetech - He says it's scheduled task.  If so defined will run whether or not the user is logged in.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, yes, *if so defined*, but the default setting is to have it run only when the user logs in. Regardless, the question is dead, so I don’t expect any new information.

Comment: @Synetech -- Yeah, I see it now -- one of those stupid "Community" updates raised this zombie.  (But you see scheduled tasks with all sorts of triggers.  Google Update, for instance, is automatically installed to run whether on not the user is logged on.)

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if it were some Google product that is causing all the trouble; their heavy-handed fascist methods are exactly the kind of thing that fouls things up.

Answer (score 1):

Try taskkill - (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(WS.10).aspx)

Taskkill

Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2000, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows XP

Ends one or more tasks or processes. Processes can be ended by process ID or image name. Taskkill replaces the kill tool.

Examples

To end the processes with process IDs 1230, 1241, and 1253, type:

taskkill /pid 1230 /pid 1241 /pid 1253

To forcefully end the process "Notepad.exe" if it was started by the system, type:

taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /im notepad.exe

Comment: @fixer1234 Updated to add some relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a runaway windows task, if I were running it as a logged in user I would use Process Explorer (procexpe.exe) and look for the related cmd.exe and kill it there, but this one is running with a user who is not logged in.
>
> I can't figure out how to kill it.

Run Process Explorer in admin-mode (i.e., with elevated privileges)—you’ll need to enter admin credentials. That way, you will have access to the processes from other users, then you can easily find and kill it (also, you can enable the `CPU History` column to see the CPU graphs of all processes which will probably help make the errant process stick out like a sore thumb.

Alternately, Task Manager will suffice for this as well; just click the `[Show processes from all users]` button at the bottom of the *Processes* tab (figure 1). Click the column-header to sort by originating user-account to make it easier to find any unexpected processes. Of course, you’ll need to add the `User Name` column (figure 2) for it to be of much use:

1. Switch to *Processes Tab*
2. Select *View → Columns*
3. Check the `[User Name]` box
4. `[OK]`

---

**Figure 1**: Screenshot of all-users button in Task Manager

[image: Screenshot of all-users button in Task Manager]

**Figure 2**: Screenshot of User Name column in Task Manager

[image: Screenshot of User Name column in Task Manager]